# HasFilter not being applied on MySql

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework-core, mysql-workbench, ef-core-5.0

Iam trying to add this index on mysql database. The unique index is created but HasFilter isValid condition is not applied. Can anyone please help me what may be issue.
**isValid** is **tinyint(1)** in the database

```
entityBuilder.HasIndex(e => new { e.LevelId, e.isValid, e.DeletedAt })
    .IsUnique()
    .HasFilter("isValid = 0");
```

Comment: Which provider? Official or Pomelo?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, Pomelo version 7.0.0

Comment: How Pomelo 7.0.0 works with EF Core 3.1? You can use only version [Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 3.2.7](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/3.2.7#dependencies-body-tab)

Comment: Apologies, Ef core 3.1 tag was added by mistake. EF Core version 5.0 is being used

Comment: Then you can use ONLY Pomelo `5.0.4`

Comment: tried that version. but still the issue exist

Comment: Any other EF Core providers are included? This functionality should work out of the box. Probably you have wrong library dependencies across the project.